# Math issue in C++

Tags: c++

I am making a code in which you input two numbers, a and b, then it calculates how many b's can be inside a, and then it displays this number with the quantity that is left. Although when a=-2147483648 and b = 10 it does the math wrong, I can find out what is the issue, even with the debugger.Thank you!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int main() {
    int multiple, a, b, rest;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    if (a > 0)
    {
        multiple = floor(a / b);
        rest = a - (multiple * b);
    }
    else
    {
        multiple = floor((a - b) / b);
        rest = (multiple*b - a);
    }

    std::cout << multiple << " " << rest << std::endl;
}
```

Result espected -214748365 2
Result given 214748363 -18

Comment: _"...it does the math wrong..."_: what result did you expect and what result did you get?

Comment: @ssovukluk OP is using `double` that's probably the problem, but without the expect/actual we can't be sure.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the answer

Comment: Even he defined variables as float, i didnt think he will use float members. Mine was just a blind guess. But you are right in your case.

Comment: I changed it to int, and that is the result

Comment: Use % mod operator? It will give what you want. 15%6 = 3

Comment: Using INT_MIN causes overflow.

Comment: To be clear, in case of, say, a = -48 and b = 10, your expected result would be multiple = -5 and rest = 2? If the question is "how many b can be inside a" I would have answered -4, with -8 left...

Comment: One possibility is that `-2147483648` is outside the range an `int` can represent, for your implementation.     You cannot expect such input to be read correctly, and give the correct value.    A second possibility is overflow in the calculations - which for an `int` gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: `floor(a / b)` and `floor((a - b) / b)` are nonsenses since `a`, `b` are integers -- there is nothing to floor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting from program to give: (-16)/6 = -3 times 6 and + 2. But it does not work in this way on computer operators. It just divides 16 by 6 and at the end it puts minus so we get -4. I made a bit changes on your code to serve on your purpose. We gotta make a program to serve on the way you want. So because your multipler is minus when a < 0, we need to add (-1) to it. So 6*(multipler - 1) + 2 == 6*(-2-1)+2 == -16 so:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int multiple, a, b, rest;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    if (a > 0)
    {
        multiple = a / b;
        rest = a - (multiple * b);
    }
    else
    {
        multiple = a / b - 1;
        rest = -(multiple*b - a);
    }

    std::cout << multiple << " " << rest << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

run:

```
./a.out 
-2147483648
10
-214748365 2
```

Comment: Your answers give me this:-214748364, but I need this:-214748365, and the second output is different depending on the answer I choose.I can't find the problem with this, it is very strange.

Comment: Im about to get home. I will help you by rewriting your code for educational purpose after like 30 mins

Comment: Wow, thank very much! I am very grateful really, I couldn't understand the issue but I do now and it works, thanks!

Comment: @polmonroig a suggestion... Even i tried to understand you, things does not work with your explanation here. Please go more stepwise and with examples while you are explaining your problem. As i started with -16/6 exmple and tell exactly what kind output you want. you are welcomed btw

Comment: I know, I was in a bit of a hurry and I am new here,thanks for de advice

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
main (){
 double multiple, a, b, rest;
 std::cin >> a >> b;
 // you have to make sure b not equal zero 
 if (b != 0){
    // when a is bigger then many b's can be inside a 
    if (a > b){
       multiple = floor (a / b);
       rest = a - (multiple * b);
    }
    // when b is bigger then no b's can be inside a 
    else if (a < b){
             multiple = 0;
             rest = a;
    }
    // when a = b  then it only one b can be inside a 
    else{
          multiple = 1;
          rest = 0;
    }
  }
 std::cout << multiple << " " << rest << std::endl;
```

its all cases coverd to calculates how many b's can be inside a and you can try the % operator it will be better

Comment: I tried your code but when a is negative it gives me always 0m which is something I don't want, b is bigger in that case but the absolute value isn't, thus your answer is right but it isn't what a I am looking for, anyways thank you very much!!

Comment: when a is negative, b in this case will be bigger as you said that's right if you want to calculate based on the absolute value you can add this lines 
before the if condition;
        a = abs(a);
        b = abs(b);

Comment: Yes you're right, but I need to add one b more: For example a= -32 b = 6; the result will be -6 becuase 6*5 = 30 + 6

Comment: did you try (  a = abs(a); b = abs(b);   )    before the if condition as i told ?